# Passing USPS eVSCertifyRequest error as MasterMID not found in database

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, usps

Using eVSCertifyRequest to create the USPS label and I am passing parameter as follows:

```
https://secure.shippingapis.com/ShippingAPI.dll?API=eVSCertify&XML=<eVSCertifyRequest USERID="XXXXXXXX">
<Option>1</Option>
<Revision></Revision>
<ImageParameters>
    <ImageParameter>4X6LABEL</ImageParameter>
</ImageParameters>
<FromName>Mitesh Jain</FromName>
<FromFirm>Mitesh Jain</FromFirm>
<FromAddress1>52 NORMANDY RD</FromAddress1>
<FromAddress2>QWE</FromAddress2>
<FromCity>MARLTON</FromCity>
<FromState>NJ</FromState>
<FromZip5>08053</FromZip5>
<FromZip4>0805</FromZip4>
<FromPhone>1234567890</FromPhone>
<POZipCode></POZipCode>
<AllowNonCleansedOriginAddr>false</AllowNonCleansedOriginAddr>
<ToName>JRC,LLC</ToName>
<ToFirm>JRC,LLC</ToFirm>
<ToAddress1>110 South 8th Street</ToAddress1>
<ToAddress2>Suite 104</ToAddress2>
<ToCity>Philadelphia</ToCity>
<ToState>PA</ToState>
<ToZip5>15001</ToZip5>
<ToZip4>1500</ToZip4>
<ToPhone>0123456789</ToPhone>
<POBox></POBox>
<AllowNonCleansedDestAddr>false</AllowNonCleansedDestAddr>
<WeightInOunces>1</WeightInOunces>
<ServiceType>PRIORITY</ServiceType>
<Container>FLAT RATE ENVELOPE</Container>
<Width></Width>
<Length></Length>
<Height></Height>
<Machinable></Machinable>
<ProcessingCategory></ProcessingCategory>
<PriceOptions></PriceOptions>
<InsuredAmount></InsuredAmount>
<AddressServiceRequested></AddressServiceRequested>
<ExpressMailOptions>
    <DeliveryOption></DeliveryOption>
    <WaiverOfSignature></WaiverOfSignature>
</ExpressMailOptions>
<ShipDate></ShipDate>
<CustomerRefNo></CustomerRefNo>
<ExtraServices>
    <ExtraService></ExtraService>
</ExtraServices>
<HoldForPickup></HoldForPickup>
<OpenDistribute></OpenDistribute>
<PermitNumber></PermitNumber>
<PermitZIPCode></PermitZIPCode>
<PermitHolderName></PermitHolderName>
<CRID></CRID>
<MID>847654321</MID>
<SenderName></SenderName>
<SenderEMail></SenderEMail>
<RecipientName></RecipientName>
<RecipientEMail></RecipientEMail>
<ReceiptOption></ReceiptOption>
<ImageType>PDF</ImageType>
<HoldForManifest>Y</HoldForManifest>
<NineDigitRoutingZip>false</NineDigitRoutingZip>
<Content>
    <ContentType>HAZMAT</ContentType>
</Content>
```

But I am getting error as below

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error>
<Number>-2147221102</Number>  
<Source>clsEVS:GetAPIRegistrationInfo</Source>
<Description>MasterMID not found in database.  </Description>
```

What else I need to pass or what I am missing in this? I had taken the reference from path https://www.usps.com/business/web-tools-apis/evs-label-api.htm#_Toc487532684.

Answer (score 2):

According to [the PDF documentation](https://www.usps.com/business/web-tools-apis/evs-label-api.htm#_Toc487532683) you need to contact USPS to get your account configured correctly. Primarily:

> - A master Mailer ID is created
>
>   - Child Mailer IDs are created for each origin site and may be created as needed by the requirements of your business units and brands.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you used the sample MID example provided rather than supplying your  actual MID. Does the request succeed when you either 1. remove the MID altogether, or 2. supply your actual MID?

Comment: how to get mid?

Comment: As per example mid is not mandatory and then after I had tried removing MID parameter but still it is asking for same

Comment: MIDs are created through the [Business Customer Gateway site](https://gateway.usps.com). Documentation on how the id utilized is [here](https://gateway.usps.com/eAdmin/view/knowledge?id=MID)

Comment: on removing MID I am getting same issue. MID is said to be not required. still getting this issue